# How to find a date and time nearest another date and time given in month/day/year hour/minute/second AM format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to find a date and time closest to another date and time I have: 1/1/2021 7:51:58 AM (I have this saved as a string called `sunrise_time`). I am looking for a code that will let me determine which of the times (listed under the `valid` column in the dataframe of the image below) is nearest:

[image]

I have read the data (the picture, which is from an excel CSV file), into python as a pandas dataframe.

The code should say that '1/1/2021 7:53:00 AM' is the nearest time.

```py
month=1
day=1
sunrise_time = sunrise_sunset.loc[sunrise_sunset['Date'] == str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/2021', 'Sunrise']
sunset_time = sunrise_sunset.loc[sunrise_sunset['Date'] == str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/2021', 'Sunset']
sunrise_time = datetime.strptime(str(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/2021 '+sunrise_time).removeprefix('0    ').removesuffix('\nName: Sunrise, dtype: object'), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

I need to figure out which time under `valid` is closest because eventually I will collect the temperature (`tmpf`) of that associated date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easier way to do so is making a substraction between the date and get the smaller one :

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime(2015,8,25,0,0,0,0)
c = a - b
c.total_seconds()
87062.729491
```

For example and find the smaller value.